# The activity is showing blank when it is opened from the Fragment Class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a fragment activity which is a listview. When the user clicks the an item from the listview it opens another activity. The new activity is loaded but shows as blank.

I have tried to recreate the activity but it does not solve the problem. I am comparatively new to Android and Java Coding. The app works fine. I can use the back button to go back to the list and click another item. The result is the same.

I tried everything possible but unable to fix it. Can some one help me on this?

Fragment Activity

```
package com.ornisoft.bloodbankapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.ornisoft.bloodbankapp.DataAdapter.MessageDataAdapter;
import com.ornisoft.bloodbankapp.DataModel.MessageDataModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MessageFragment  extends Fragment {
    DatabaseHelper db;
    ArrayList<MessageDataModel> MessageDataModelArrayList;
    MessageDataAdapter MessageDataAdapter;

    Context context;
    ListView lvMessages;



    public MessageFragment(){}
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_message, container, false);
        context = container.getContext();

        lvMessages = view.findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);
        lvMessages.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent  intent =  new Intent(getActivity(), MessageActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("id",l);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        loadMessages();
        return view;
    }
    public void loadMessages(){
        MessageDataModelArrayList = db.getMessages();
        MessageDataAdapter = new MessageDataAdapter(context,MessageDataModelArrayList);
        lvMessages.setAdapter(MessageDataAdapter);
        MessageDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Message Activity

```
package com.ornisoft.bloodbankapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper db;
    int messageID;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Hello world " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /*messageID= Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
        MessageModel messageModel = db.getMessage(messageID);*/
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MessageActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to see "TextView" message on center of the screen?

Comment: Can you see the toast? You could also try changing the textview colour and size just to be sure. Depending on your style it could be blank as the background.

Comment: First make sure that you are clicking the correct view from the list item using log or toast. Then check the newely opened activity (MessageActivity) has layout with proper view from IDE layout design. As you are new to to check this you can also go in manifest file and make this activity as launcher activity and see the layout you are getting. Let us know also your test result.

Comment: @Can you share you screenshot of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I am using the wrong create class on the MessageActivity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

when I changed it to

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

the problem is solved and it works perfect.

Thank you all.